# Google Sheet "Array Formula Error" in using Ifnumber

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, worksheet

`=if(ISNUMBER(search("Introduction to Computer",K2:K)),"ILocal","Far")`

The above is the code i used for Display the Local  but when i add "Array Formula Like this

`=ARRAYFORMULA(if(ISNUMBER(search("Introduction to Computer",K2:K)),"Local","Far"))`

its show #REF! i already tried placing arrayformula after "if" and before "isnumber" before "search" but it just showing "N/A" Can anyone please point me to something on what i did wrong here? i'm having a hard time with this one

This is my Column K or my sample data. I'm trying to display "Local" or "Far" to the whole Column

```
|Column K                   |
|:----                      |    
|Microsoft Excel            |
|Introduction to Computer   |
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using Googlesheets? As you have tagged Excel - these are NOT always the same.

Comment: `Introduction to Computer` is a single word. How it will return array output? Show your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(""&K2:K; "Introduction to Computer"); "Local"; ))
```

Comment: It's shoW #REF!

Comment: @ChristianJoshuaMendigoria this formula should be used only in row 2 and the whole column should be empty

Comment: i need it for the whole column @player

Comment: @ChristianJoshuaMendigoria it auto-populates for the whole column from row 2